# EmotionJS with typescript doesn't pass theme type to props in styled components

Tags: typescript, emotion

### emotion.d.ts

```
import '@emotion/react';

declare module '@emotion/react' {
    export interface Theme {
        colors: {
            primaryColor: string;
            accentColor: string;
        };
    }
}
```

### App.tsx

```
import { Theme, ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';

const theme: Theme = {
    colors: {
        accentColor: 'hotpink',
        primaryColor: 'aqua',
    },
};
...

return (
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>

...
```

### Button.tsx

```
const StyledButton = styled.a`
    ${({ theme }) =>
        `background-color: ${theme.colors.accentColor};`
    }`;
```

### tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "typeRoots": ["src/@types"],
        "jsx": "react",
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["src/@types/*"]
        }
    },
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

```
src
|=>@types
  |> emotion.d.ts
|=> components
|> App.tsx
```

Property 'colors' does not exist on type 'object'.

Am I doing something wrong or did I misread the documentation ?

Right now I am manually adding the theme by passing it to the styled constructor :

```
type StyledProps = Pick<ButtonProps, 'bgColor' | 'fColor'> & { theme: Theme };

const StyledButton = styled.a<StyledProps>`
...
```

Removing the passed type doesnt't help either.

It seems like the d.ts file is picked up correctly, because I can import the correct theme type from `"@emtion/react"` with `import { Theme } from "@emotion/react"` and use that to type the `props.theme` in the styled components

### [Repro](https://github.com/Twiggeh/EmotionJSThemeTypescriptBug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your provided code, I would think the error is supposed to be:

```
Property 'accentColor' does not exist on type 'Theme'. // instead of object
```

Anyway your `Theme` object now nested by `colors` at the top level so you might change to:

```js
const StyledButton = styled.a`
  ${({ theme }) =>
      `background-color: ${theme.colors.accentColor};` // `accentColor` is nested in `colors`
  }`;
```

Keep in mind, you also need to include your defined type in build process in `tsconfig.json` file via `include` option.

#### Update regarding to unable override `Theme` via the custom type file

As I've seen the `styled` type only consume `Theme` object from `@emotion/react` at least from version `^11.0.0`.

In short, you have to update `@emotion/styled` to from this version `^11.0.0` to make it work as expected:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah that is a typo in the question, not in the actual code, sorry. I'll add my filestructure and the tsconfig shortly

Comment: Looks like nothing weird with given code. Do you have a reproducible repo?

Comment: Yep, just added it & a bug report to emotionjs

Comment: it seems to be empty for now?

Comment: yeah I got an econnreset error when trying to push. Should be good now

Comment: Thanks, I did run yarn upgrade but that apparently that didn't go through property ;-;

Comment: Omg, what a savior.. updating the @emotion/styled worked for me.